# ReportViewer scroll bar issue

Tags: vb.net, forms, scrollbar, reportviewer

[image: before]
[image: after]

Above issue will happen when:-

STEP1: Open the report form

STEP2: Generate a report and scroll to right

STEP3: Close report form

STEP4: Reopen report form

As you can see some of the column on left hand side are missing, the only way to avoid this problem is you must scroll it back to left before you close the form otherwise you need to restart the application. And same thing happen to vertical scroll bar, if you close the form without scroll it back to top, you will missing some row when you reopen the form.

*Maximize or Resize the form cant fix it also

Below is the report form coding

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting
Public Class Report
Private Sub Report_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.scr_report.RefreshReport()
End Sub

Private Sub dtp_from_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtp_from.ValueChanged, dtp_to.ValueChanged
    Dim currDTP As DateTimePicker = sender
    dtp_from.Checked = currDTP.Checked
    dtp_to.Checked = currDTP.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub btn_generate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_generate.Click
    Dim query As String = ""

    Select Case cb_report.Text
       Case "xxx"
       'some query
    End Select

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet1

    da.Fill(ds.Tables(0))

    scr_report.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local

    scr_report.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

    scr_report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0)))

    scr_report.RefreshReport()

    Me.Text = $"Report ({cb_report.Text})"
End Sub
End Class
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `scr_report.Clear()` just before the `RefreshReport()` on the generate sub.

Comment: @Jaxedin still cant